# QIcon with SVG appears black

Tags: qt, svg, highdpi, qicon

I need to support high DPI displays with my Qt 5.9.1 application and I'm looking for a solution to scale the QIcons used by the app.

I'm currently only targeting Windows 7 and 10.

So far, for non-high DPI displays (Windows 7), I used .ico files for icons that appear at different resolutions.

I've also got some icons as .png files when they're only used at a single resolution.

With high-DPI displays, under Windows 10, when the user applies a zoom factor which scales the app, the icons end-up scaled but blurred.

I've tested adding high-res png files named with the '@2x' suffix, but the scaling blurs the icons.

Seeing this I thought I'd try using .svg files instead as those should scale, but they appear black when used with QIcons. This post implies 'fill' color is not supported for QIcons: [Qt support for coloring SVG in a QIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096162/qt-support-for-coloring-svg-in-a-qicon)

Has anyone managed to get .svg files to work with QIcons? Am I even on the right track with .svg to support high-DPI displays and still get crisp icons? If not, what approach are people out there taking?

Comment: try `setIcon(QPixmap("..."))`; afaik the implementation of `setIcon` with `QIcon` differs from the one with `QPixmap`... I believe that I've read about that issue

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem with QT 5.6. I edited .svg files and I replaced `<style>` by `<style type="text/css">` and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of code from my project:


ui->pushButtonIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/simplebrowser.svg"));

I am setting *.svg image to QPushButton(). Image is added to my resources in project.

[image]

Comment: The icon appears black when I do that. Which version of Qt are you using? Could you post your SVG on here so I could try it out?

Comment: I am using Qt5.8. Here is image https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7c_-N_LaeQid1QtV0dBa2RtQkU. POssibly you have some QWidget over it?